# ngrx/store/store has no exported member "dispatcher"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ngrx

Recently I did an update of my angular packages inside of a .net core application and after doing that I began running into 4 errors related to items inside the node_modules folder. I have read a couple of other similar issues on SO which did not help resolve this particular issue. It may worth noting that I can't seem to duplicate this on another laptop I have running the same code. I have attempted to revert back my angular version, deleted the node_modules folder and re-ran  install of angular. To take a step further I've even completely uninstalled angular, updated node.js to the latest stable release and re-installed angular to no avail Any help resolving this would be much appreciated.

[image: Angular build error]

[image: Angular build error]

Comment: I don't see NgRx as a dependency?

Comment: @timdeschryver ngrx is installed in the project. I'm not sure why its not being reflected in the version output above.